# Getting GPS location of Mp4 file using metadata-extractor

Tags: metadata-extractor

I am looking for a solution to get GPS location of any video like mp4. Does metadata-extractor support this ?

Thanks,

Op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metadata Extractor doesn't currently support GPS from any video format. Currently only the .NET implementation handles any video formats, and only QuickTime framed video at that.

Support in the Java version is being tracked by this issue:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/issues/127

Comment: Thanks for you comments Drew. Image library working great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to add, this is an old question/answer - the latest version appears to access the GPS location details.